# RubyGem download number seems artificially high. Are there bots that download from RubyGems.org?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I just uploaded a RubyGem two days ago. It doesn't do much, but it is a wrapper for part of the Facebook Graph API. Today, out of curiosity, I checked the gem's download number, and it was at 300 or so, which was very surprisingly high. I'm wondering if bots download from RubyGems.org, or is there actually a possibility that my gem has been downloaded 300+ times by developers?

Comment: This is not really a fit for Stack Overflow. Short answer though: Congratulations that the Ruby community took an interest in your gem. Keep writing gems!

Comment: There are at least 50 mirrors of rubygems, possibly quite a bit more.  Every version of every gem I've ever uploaded had at least 50 downloads, even though most of my gems aren't generally that useful.

Answer (score 14):

Everybody know that `bundle install` is a bit slow. So someone can consider to keep rubygems mirror locally.

There is the gem for this task: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems-mirror

So that's why download number is high.

Answer (score 2):

I'm certain bots influence the count. I released several updates and version bumps to a gem I wrote over the course of a day or so. Then the highest release remained unchanged for months. The gem hasn't really caught on. If I look at the download stats, the totals for the releases that were only the latest release for a few hours have similar totals (and download patterns) to the version of the gem that has been the latest version for months and months.

That said, my totals peaked at around 30, so maybe there are some real users in there. If you want to know for sure, make a quick improvement and bump the version and compare the usage trends.

Comment: same measure for my little gem (ruiby) : 30 downloads at each update, and no user (a big bug with linux was not signaled...)